# How to create a list from parsed HTML text with Angular.js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

For my application, I need to load data from HTML. On a list element I need to parse the UL children elements (LI) and serialize those elements (map to array) in a model. From this model I will create a modal view, recreate a list and modify this list.

I use JQuery and AngularJs. I have created a directive and parse the list when initializing and store everything in a model. But when creating a new list from the array with a template and ng-repeat, I get original data + 3 extra values.

**Html:**

```html
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <ul ng-my-list>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```js
app = angular.module "MyApp", []

app.directive 'ngMyList', ->
    linker = (scope, element, attrs) ->  
        scope.items = {
            entry: element.find('li').map ->
                $(this).text()
        }

    {
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items.entry"> > {{item}}</li></ul>'
        replace: true
        restrict: 'A'
        link: linker
        scope: {}
    }

angular.bootstrap document, ['MyApp']
```

I have extracted the code to http://jsfiddle.net/sbusso/NRLUH/. In this example I can't even get values from original list.

What s wrong in this code? How can I get ng-repeat ignoring extra array values?

**UPDATE**

adding a splice(0) clean the array and I get my result

```
entry: element.find('li').map (->
                $(this).text()).splice(0)
```

Is there something specific between AngularJS and JQuery ? this code was working with Backbone.

**UPDATE 2**

In example I have to use context to get same result as my application:

```
    scope.items = {
        entry: $(element.context).find('li').map( ->
            $(this).text()
            ).splice(0)
    }
```

Only issue still: why map / ng-repeat doenst play well together (if I dont add splice(0)) ?

updated code to show working list + 3 extra lines: http://jsfiddle.net/sbusso/NRLUH/5/

Comment: could you just provide ->input and expected output

Comment: input is the list, output expected, in this example, is the same list built by the directive from parsed data

Comment: `jQuery(selector).map()` returns jQuery object. Use `get()` to unwrap from `jQuery` object

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rcSXk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to charlietfl the complete answer is:

- use `element.context` to get the original DOM element
- use **get()** in `JQuery(selector).map().get()` to unwrap JQuery object and give a clean array to ng-repeat